# What's the difference between the various methods for producing for loops?

Tags: loops, etoolbox, pgffor

I've been wondering about the various methods available for looping over a comma separated list and the like.  In particular, I was wondering about their various strengths and weaknesses.  In other words, I was wondering about such things as the following (but not solely limited to this list):

1. whether or not they're expandable,
2. how they handle empty items,
3. how they handle extraneous leading and trailing spaces
4. whether you can use `\def`/`\edef` or need to use `\gdef`/`\xdef` to save information from within the loop for later use.

In no particular order, here's a list of looping methods I'm familiar with.  In the following list `\current@item` represents a macro, taking one argument, for formatting the current item in iteration.

Using commands from the `2ekernal`:

```
%% \@for
\def\@for@myloop#1{%%
  \@for \x:=#1 \do{\current@item \x}}

%% \@tfor (not a comma separated list--probably shouldn't be here)
\def\@tfor@myloop#1{%%
  \@tfor \x:=#1 \do{\if,\x\relax\else\current@item \x\fi}}
```

Using `etoolbox` package

```
%% `etoolbox`:  need to be careful whether passed a macro:
%%  in that case expansion may be necessary to that the 
%%  delimiters are visible to `\forcsvlist`
\def\etoolbox@myloop#1{%%
  \expandafter\forcsvlist
  \expandafter\current@item
  \expandafter{#1}}
```

Using `pgffor` package

```
%% pgffor
\def\pgffor@myloop#1{%%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {\current@item \x}}
```

A homebrew method:

```
%% version a la `ae`
\def\@ae@myloop#1,#2\@nil{%%
  \current@item{#1}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \@ae@myloop#2\@nil
   \fi
}
\def\ae@myloop#1{%%
  \@ae@myloop#1,\@nil
}
```

Then there are also the various `expl3` methods such as (there are quite a few, so this is hardly exhaustive):

```
\tl_map_inline:nn
\tl_map_function:Nn
\clist_map_inline:Nn
\seq_map_inline:Nn
```

Here is a MWE illustrating the results of each of these (including one LaTeX3 version):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperheight=15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter

\def\my@item@count{0}
\def\step@my@counter{\xdef\my@item@count{\number\numexpr\my@item@count+1\relax}}
%% \rules to emphasize how spaces are seen and treated!
\def\current@item#1{\step@my@counter\item \rule{0.4pt}{2ex}#1\rule{0.4pt}{2ex}}

%% `etoolbox`
\def\etoolbox@myloop#1{%%
  \forcsvlist \current@item {#1}}
  %% but if passed a macro, then it  first needs to be expanded so the delimiters are visible to `\forcsvlist`.  You'll need to write
  %% \expandafter\forcsvlist \expandafter\current@item \expandafter{#1}}

%% \@for
\def\@for@myloop#1{%%
  \@for \x:=#1 \do{\current@item \x}}

%% \@tfor
\def\@tfor@myloop#1{%%
  \@tfor \x:=#1 \do{\current@item \x}}

%% pgffor
\def\pgffor@myloop#1{%%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {\current@item \x}}

%% version a la `ae`
\def\@ae@myloop#1,#2\@nil{%%
  \current@item{#1}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \@ae@myloop#2\@nil
   \fi
}
\def\ae@myloop#1{%%
  \@ae@myloop#1,\@nil
}

\def\listoffruit#1#2#3{%%
  \def\my@item@count{0}%%
  \noindent
  List of type \texttt{#1}: \parbox[t]{3in}{\raggedright#3}
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=4pt,itemsep=2pt]
    \csname#1@myloop\endcsname{#2}%%
  \end{itemize}
  Total number of bulleted items: \my@item@count
  \par \vspace{2ex}\hrule\par \vspace{2ex}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expl@myloop}{ m }
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{\current@item {##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother
\def\apples{apples}
\def\bananas{bananas}
\def\cherries{cherries}

\begin{document}

\listoffruit{etoolbox}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}{Ignores leading spaces and empty items. Trailing spaces not ignored.}

\listoffruit{@for}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}{Empty lines and trailing or leading spaces not ignored.  Something goes on with last item in list.}

\listoffruit{@tfor}{\apples,{} {oranges}\bananas\cherries}{Spaces ignored, all other token respected, bracketed tokens treated as one.}

\listoffruit{pgffor}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}{Ignores leading spaces, empty items and trailing spaces not ignored.}

\listoffruit{ae}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}{Leading or trailing spaces not ignored.  Empty items not ignored.}

\listoffruit{expl}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}{Trailing or leading spaces ignored.   Empty items ignored.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Issues I'm aware of:

- I believe `\@for` is not expandable,
- `\cslist_map_inline:nn` is expandable but with limitations: i.e., it is not expandable in an `f`-type argument.
- `pgffor`'s `\foreach` loop in executed within a group.  So you need to use `\gdef` or `\xdeg` to save information from within the group for later use.  I've not fully explored which others of the loops presented here have a similar *short-coming* (not sure that's the right choice of word).  I have no idea whether `\foreach` is expandable or not.
- Some methods handle their lists rather nicely whether passed explicitly or implicitly via a macro.  For example, `pgffor`'s `\foreach` knows what do to with a list passed via a macro.  `etoolbox`'s `\forcsvlist` needs that macro to first be expanded:  hence the reason my first illustration of a `\forcslist` is as complicated as it is.

So what I'm interested in here is:

1. Responses which address the strengths and weaknesses  of the different approaches presented here as itemized at the beginning of this post, but not necessarily limited to those suggestions since I may be unaware of other important issues..  For example, I'm not really sure which are expandable.
2. Responses which introduce other methods for iterating over a list of items along with their known weaknesses and strengths.
3. Responses which can illustrate realistic examples for which one would want to use such a loop in an expandable context
4. Reponses which illustrate how one can save information gathered  from
   within the group for later use.

Comment: There is also [`forloop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop).

Comment: @marczellm `forloop` is for looping a counter: much more like `expl3`'s `\int_step_function:nnnN` or similar.

Comment: Serendipity. The way you passed that list to be directly used by `\foreach` saved me asking a question. I'm on a steep learning curve with `tikz` and `pgfplots` and as yet just getting started on loops and your question is right up my alley. Can't wait to see the answers.

Comment: Why `\expandafter\ifx\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`? The shorter version `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is safe and reliable. About the bulk of the question: remove the braces around the items and try also with leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @egreg I used `\ifx` because I understand it better than `\fi`.  I'm not really sure what you mean in your suggestion for improving the readability of the question.  Could you post a link to another question that does something similar to what you're trying to suggestion?

Comment: @A.Ellett It was not about readability; some loop constructs do not remove trailing or leading spaces from items.

Comment: @egreg Then that's getting to the heart of what I'm after.  It seems that there are various delicacies with some of the approaches that are not present for others.  I was trying to be too clever at too late an hour by smuggling in the LaTeX3 answer, and so wrote it in a manner that would work for all the approaches listed:  notably because of `\@tfor`.

Comment: `\@tfor` is really out of place here, because it doesn't manage comma separated lists.

Comment: There is also http://www.ctan.org/pkg/loops

Comment: Another method that you should probably considered is `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, which comes with the `pgfplots` package. As I understand it, it's intended to be identical to the `\foreach` command from `pgffor` except that it is not executed within a group. However, I'm not qualified to understand any more subtle differences.  Also, short of (possibly) copying code from the source, I don't know of a way to get this method without using the entire `pgfplots` package, which drags `TikZ` in with it.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I think you should nevertheless still post your suggestion as an answer.  Others will come along a make suggestions and point out strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @A.Ellet: Since the author of `pgfplots` is active on TeX.SE, I'm going to wait a bit to see if he responds first. In the meantime, here's a potentially relevant answer he wrote http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/484 as well as another answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43355/484 by a different author demonstrating one use of `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`.

Comment: Where is the `\multido`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I propose a different definition of `\current@item`

```
\def\current@item#1{%
  \stepcounter{item@count}
  \item $|$#1$|$\ $|$\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}$|$%
}
```

so the output also shows what's really passed as its argument. Also I changed the complicated management of `\my@item@count` with a simple counter. I don't comment about `\@tfor`, which is a different tool not designed for comma separated lists.

1. `etoolbox`: `\forcsvlist` doesn't remove trailing spaces; your definition is too complicated, because

   ```
   %% `etoolbox`
   \def\etoolbox@myloop#1{%%
     \forcsvlist\current@item{#1}}
   ```

   suffices. Items are passed explicitly.
2. `\@for` is the basic tool defined in the LaTeX kernel. Leading and trailing spaces are not removed. Items are passed as `\x`, the control sequence used after `\@for`.
3. `\foreach` doesn't remove trailing spaces. Items are passed as `\x`, the control sequence used after `\foreach`.
4. `ae` is basically like `\@for`, although it works by expansion. Leading and trailing spaces are not removed. Items are passed explicitly.
5. `expl` removes leading and trailing spaces, but also empty items; items are passed explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperheight=15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{item@count}
%% \rules to emphasize how spaces are seen and treated!
\def\current@item#1{%
  \stepcounter{item@count}
  \item $|$#1$|$\ $|$\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}$|$%
}

%% `etoolbox`
\def\etoolbox@myloop#1{%%
  \forcsvlist\current@item{#1}}

%% \@for
\def\@for@myloop#1{%%
  \@for \x:=#1\do{\current@item \x}}

%% pgffor
\def\pgffor@myloop#1{%%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {\typeout{pgf:\x}\current@item \x}}

%% version a la `ae`
\def\@ae@myloop#1,#2\@nil{%%
  \current@item{#1}%%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \@ae@myloop#2\@nil
   \fi
}
\def\ae@myloop#1{%%
  \@ae@myloop#1,\@nil
}

\def\listoffruit#1#2{%%
  \setcounter{item@count}{0}%%
  \noindent
  List of type \texttt{#1}
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=4pt,itemsep=2pt]
    \csname#1@myloop\endcsname{#2}%%
  \end{itemize}
  Total number of bulleted items: \arabic{item@count}%
  \par \vspace{2ex}\hrule\par \vspace{2ex}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expl@myloop}{ m }
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{\current@item {##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffruit{etoolbox}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}

\listoffruit{@for}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}

\listoffruit{pgffor}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}

\listoffruit{ae}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}

\listoffruit{expl}{apples,, oranges, bananas ,cherries}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd add another `expl3` loop, that also considers empty items:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\seq@myloop}{ m }
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \current@item {##1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(of course, using `\l_tmpa_seq` is discouraged, better allocate a new variable).

[image]

The comparison should leave no doubt. The only place where `\foreach` is superior is in its treatment of “incomplete lists”, such as `1,2,...,20`.

Comment: The only reason my `\forcsvlist` is as complicated as presented is because I frequently pass my comma separated lists via macros.  This is not necessarily an issue with `pgffor`'s `\foreach`.  It **would** be an issue with my *homebrew* example.

Comment: @A.Ellett In my opinion, the macros for dealing with explicit and implicit (given via a macro) lists should be different: you can get wrong result if an explicit list starts with a macro which will be expanded too early.

Comment: I am aware of that issue.  Do you have suggestions for a better approach?  Or are you suggesting that's an entirely different question?  Actually, this who question arose because I had a list saved in a macro and I wanted to use `etoolbox`'s `\forlistloop`.  But apparently the `<listmacro>` expected needs to be built internally which didn't work for me because of how I was generating the list.

Comment: Incidentally, I like your idea for illustrating what was passed via `\detokenize`.

Comment: @A.Ellett For expandable loops, if your list can be gathered before in a `clist` variable, you have `\clist_map_function:NN` which is expandable. I'm sure there's code around for expandably removing leading and trailing space, but I don't know how robust they are (if Bruno's not able to do it, …)

Comment: @egreg Inspired by the OP I tried the list passing idea which worked well, but I very quickly got into trouble with the list as macro scenario. Should this be asked as a separate question or is there already a detailed answer somewhere? I'm restricting myself to `tikz`/`pgfplots` based solutions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\drawCircle}[1]{\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (#1);}
    \begin{filecontents*}{testlua.lua}
        for i=1,10 do
            tex.print("\\drawCircle{",0.1*i,"}")
        end
    \end{filecontents*}
    \directlua{dofile('testlua.lua')}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like this is rather an answer but another method worth to be mentioned in the question ;-)

Comment: To make this an "Answer" you should add discussion of how it compares with the other methods.