# Why is the `pgffor` package messing with my scope?

Tags: pgffor

I have a several rather lengthy documents with numbered points (catechism
questions) that I would like to be able to selectively include in other
documents using a utility function that uses a range argument. I ran into
trouble and eventually traced it to the way the `\foreach` seems to run in its
own private scope of some kind. The loops seem to iterate properly, but things
set inside them (such as `\newif` definitions or toggles from the `etoolbox`
package don't seem to stick.

This fails miserably:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\wkk}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
        \providetoggle{wkk\x}
    }
    \foreach \x in {#1}{%
        \toggletrue{wkk\x}
    }
    % In a real example the following content would be \input here
    \iftoggle{wkk1}{output 1 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk2}{output 2 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk3}{output 3 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk4}{output 4 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk5}{output 5 }{}
}

\begin{document}

\wkk{2,...,4}

\end{document}
```

Yet if I replace the `\foreach` loops with exactly what they should be doing in the above example, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\wkk}[1]{%
    \providetoggle{wkk1}
    \providetoggle{wkk2}
    \providetoggle{wkk3}
    \providetoggle{wkk4}
    \providetoggle{wkk5}
    \toggletrue{wkk2}
    \toggletrue{wkk3}
    \toggletrue{wkk4}
    % In a real example the following content would be \input here
    \iftoggle{wkk1}{output 1 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk2}{output 2 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk3}{output 3 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk4}{output 4 }{}
    \iftoggle{wkk5}{output 5 }{}
}

\begin{document}

\wkk{2,...,4}

\end{document}
```

Obviously these are kind of clumsy MWE's and I would be including the content
from an external source file that was marked up with the correct toggles.

What am I doing wrong with the `pgffor` package? Or **is there a conceptually
better way to do this?**

Comment: See section 83 of the PGF manual: *Note that in each execution of commands the commands are put in a TEX group. This means that
local changes to counters inside commands do not persist till the next iteration*

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140907/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-for-producing-for-loops: `\foreach` uses a group.

Comment: `\iftoggle` does not survive any loop style I know -- I detected that too -- unfortunately. I think, there is always a grouping within loops, for some `\ifthenelse` queries, whatever

Comment: Based on comments, I need a different way to do this conceptually. Can that be answered in this question as is or do I need to edit it?

Comment: @daleif: `\setcounter` is not group-safe, or am I completely confused? So at least LaTeX - counters are not safe from being changed in a group.

Comment: `\setcounter` is global.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each cycle of `\pgffor` is performed in a group, so the definition of the toggles and the setting don't survive them.

One can solve the issue with `\toggletrue` by writing `\global\toggletrue`, but there's no “global `\providetoggle`”. However you can define your own:

```
\let\gprovidetoggle\providetoggle
\patchcmd{\gprovidetoggle}{\cslet}{\global\cslet}{}{}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\gprovidetoggle\providetoggle
\patchcmd{\gprovidetoggle}{\cslet}{\global\cslet}{}{}

\newcommand{\wkk}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
        \gprovidetoggle{wkk\x}%
        \global\togglefalse{wkk\x}% set it to false
    }%
    \foreach \x in {#1}{%
        \global\toggletrue{wkk\x}%
    }%
    % In a real example the following content would be \input here
    \iftoggle{wkk1}{output 1 }{}%
    \iftoggle{wkk2}{output 2 }{}%
    \iftoggle{wkk3}{output 3 }{}%
    \iftoggle{wkk4}{output 4 }{}%
    \iftoggle{wkk5}{output 5 }{}%
}

\begin{document}

\wkk{2,...,4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My original attempt at this used `\expandafter\newif\csname ifwkk\x\endcsname` etc. which makes the markup in the source file a little easier. I switched to etoolbox toggles when I couldn't make that go. Is that potentially a slightly simpler route to go than this one? If so how do I make those \if definitions global?

Comment: @Caleb Your loops work unchanged if you use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` (requires `\usepackage{pgfplots}`) instead of `\foreach`.

Comment: `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` makes my original code using `\newif`s work perfectly. Would you mind adding a note about that to this answer?

Comment: @Caleb With toggles it's easier, in my opinion.